# C# Jira SDK create issue with Epic Name

Tags: c#, rest, sdk, jira

Im using C# Jira SDK

How can i create an Epic Issue ?

If i try this code:

```
 jira = new Jira("https://jira.com", LoginUI.username, LoginUI.password);

 var issue = jira.CreateIssue(projectKey);

 issue.Type = "Epic";
 issue.Summary = "Test Summary";
 string[] epicname = { "test" };
 issue.CustomFields.Add("Epic Name", epicname);

 issue.SaveChanges();
```

I get an Error Message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in Atlassian.Jira.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not find custom field with name 'Epic
>   Name' on the JIRA server. Make sure this field is available when
>   editing this issue. For more information see JRA-6857

Answer (score 0):

Try using using the REST Client instead:

```
 jira = new Jira.CreateRestClient("https://jira.com", LoginUI.username, LoginUI.password, null);

 var issue = jira.CreateIssue(projectKey);

 issue.Type = "Epic";
 issue.Summary = "Test Summary";
 string epicname = "test";
 issue.CustomFields.Add("Epic Name", epicname);

 issue.SaveChanges();
```

You should then be able to set the Epic Name or other custom fields. I have tested this using the latest 5.8.0 build.